# Linear programming - multi-objective optimization. How to build single function

Tags: linear-programming

I have LP problem
It is similar to assignment problem for workers
I have three assignments with constraint scores(Constraint 1 is more important than constraint 2)

```
                     Constraint1    Constraint2   
 assign1             590            5              

 assign2             585            580              

 assign3             585            336
```

My current greedy solver will compare assignments by the first constraint. The best one becomes a solution. Solver will compare Constraint 2  if and only if he found two assignments with the same score value for previous constraint and so on.

For a given example in the first round assign2 and assign3 will be chosen because they have the same lowest constraint score. After second round solver choses assign3. So I need a cost function which will represent that behavior.

So I expect the

> assign1_cost > assign2_cost > assign3_cost.

Is it posible to do?
I believe that I can apply some weighted math function or something like that.

Comment: Not sure if this is an LP. Looks like you have requirements that would take some if-then-else logic to implement, looping over rounds. Does it have to be an LP?

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to do this simply, that I know of:

1. Assume that you can put an upper bound on each objective function (besides the first). Then you rewrite your objective as follows: `(objective_1 * max_2 + objective_2) * max_3 + objective_3` and so on, and minimize said objective. For your example, say you know that `objective_2` will be less than 1000. You can then solve, minimizing `objective_1*1000 + objective_2`. This may fail with some solvers if your upper bounds are too large.
2. This method requires `n` solver iterations, where `n` is the number of objectives, but is general - it doesn't require you to know upper bounds beforehand. Solve, minimizing `objective_1` and ignoring the other objective functions. Add a constraint that `objective_1 == <value you just got>`. Solve, minimizing `objective_2` and ignoring the remaining objective functions. Repeat until you've gone through every objective function.